# FF Addon send user to their homepage?

Tags: firefox-addon

What is the command to send a user to their homepage?

Do I have to do something with gBrowser.webNavigation

Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think all you need to do is get the user's homepage from the `browser.startup.homepage` preference, and then call `gBrowser.loadURI(homepageURI);`